# Is it true that a hard drive need to be used once in a while to stay alive?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, storage, usb-storage, hard-drive-failure

I have heard someone saying that someone else said hard-disks need to be "moved" once in a while, meaning it has to spin or data has to read or written to once in a while or something like that.

I am thinking about a external harddisk just as backup, and I will probably only move data on there every 6 month or so. The other time it will be sitting in a "safe place" somewhere powered off. I guess that's perfectly fine.

I could imagine this somehow to be true since there is something with magnetic force going on inside... and that some persistent conditions might be bad for it, that the data might "fade" or something.

But just assuming I would never use the disk in 2 years, is it bad for it to never be used through all that time? Or is this just a myth? Will its live expectancy actually be better that way or worse?

And I by the way know that Hard-disks are not the professional way for long time backup, please just ignore that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have heard someone saying that someone else said hard-disks need to be "moved" once in a while meaning it has to spin or data has to read or written to once in a while or something like that.

That is true of most [RAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAM), but no, it is not true of [hard-drives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_Drive).

[(S)DRAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SDRAM) is volatile memory which must have the data re-written to it regularly to avoid it “fading”. There are [non-volatile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-volatile_random-access_memory) types of RAM which are used for things like the BIOS and video-game saves, but the kind used for the “memory” of a computer is volatile.

Another source of confusion might be that [data stored on tape](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_tape_data_storage) does indeed tend to “fade” over time. Because the tape is thin and spooled, the layers of tape contain a small magnetic field in such close proximity to each other, they will eventually cause [degradation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_preservation#Magnetic_media.2C_video_cassettes.2C_tapes.2C_hard_drives), so reading the tape before it degrades and writing it back is indeed necessary to avoid data loss.

> I am thinking about a external harddisk just as backup, and I will probably only move data on there every 6 month or so. The other time it will sitting in a "save place" somewhere powered off. I guess thats perfectly fine.

Why yes, yes it is.

> I could image this somehow to be true since there is something with magnetic force going on inside ... and that some persistent conditions might be bad for it, that the data might "fade" or something.

Not quite. While it is true that hard-drives use magnets, they actually [contain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_Drive#Components) a “super” neodymium magnet which is used to control the read head. This magnet is quite strong and rests very close to the platters, yet does not wipe out the disk, so you can rest assured that any magnetic field from outside the drive [won’t have much (immediate) effect](https://superuser.com/questions/113430/).

> But just assuming I would never use the Disk in 2 Years is it bad for it to never used in all that time? Or is this just a Myth? Will its live expectancy actually be better that way or worse?

The data won’t “fade” (at least not after only two years), but depending on the environment you store it in, other problems could arise. For one thing, you don't want to let it be too humid (which is why manufacturers specifically store and ship them with packets of [desiccant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dessicant)).

> And I by the way know that Hard-disks are not the Professional way for long time backup. So please stay on topic.

Why not? They hold up sufficiently well and are sufficiently cheap that they actually *are* a good general-purpose backup. Professionals with super-important data might use higher-quality drives, but there is nothing wrong with keeping an extra copy on a hard-drive. In fact, storage of all kinds is usually cheap enough that you can keep a copy on a hard-drive, flash-drive, memory-card, and even tape. That way you will maximize the chances of [retaining at least one good copy](https://superuser.com/questions/454605/) of any given file.

> With "magnetic force in there" I meant exactly what you are talking about. So this magnetic charge might go away after 10 years you say. So if I take that drive for a run after 9 years this magnetic charges not get renewed? Do I actually need to rewrite the data to make that happen? Or you mean that the disk will maybe lose its data after 10 years either way its its running daily or never ran at all? – Wayne's World 5 mins ago

Yes absent a strong external magnetic field, it will usually degrade over a few decades, but that is [well past the](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MTBF) [expected lifetime of most drives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_disk_drive_failure#Hard-drives) anyway. They used to have lifetime warranties, then five years, then three. They get shorter and shorter and will likely die of other causes long before the data degrades.

Comment: Are you saying this in the last paragraph: No rewriting of the data does not recharge this magnetic charges on a drive? So just hypothetical (as everything we talk about here is, just trying to understand the technical stuff) If the drive would live after 9 years the rewrite of the data would have no effect? Or what. What you mean by "absent a strong external magnetic field" is there such a field when the drive is on or written to? Are you speaking about the earth field?

Comment: I am still confused because @PaulGreen said that the earth field is actually messing with the data over long time. You say the date will fade if a magnetic field is missing? You kind of dodged my multi part question there. A clear yes or no would be nice. On the Harddrive not best backup: It might be that that have hanged and companies just buy new drives and trow away the old ones, but AFAIK Harddrives were considered bad for serious backups back in the days. TAPE drives and such were better for it.

Comment: `Are you saying No rewriting of the data does not recharge this magnetic charges on a drive? So just hypothetical, If the drive would live after 9 years the rewrite of the data would have no effect? Or what. I am still confused because @PaulGreen said that the earth field is actually messing with the data over long time.`   The magnetic particles in the platter will eventually lose their orientation due to the pull of all of the magnetic fields around the drive (esp. the Earth’s magnetic field), but it takes a really long time because the fields are weak.

Comment: `What you mean by "absent a strong external magnetic field" is there such a field when the drive is on or written to?`   No.   `Are you speaking about the earth field?`   No, a *much* stronger mag-field.   `You say the date will fade if a magnetic field is missing?`   Huh? No.   `You kind of dodged my multi part question there.`   Actually, I addressed every single point.   `A clear yes or no would be nice.`   That’s not possible; you didn’t ask a yes-or-no question.

Comment: `On the Harddrive not best backup: … AFAIK Harddrives were considered bad for serious backups back in the days. TAPE drives and such were better for it.`   You have misunderstood the reason for that. The reason that tape was preferred had **nothing** to do with reliability, it was all about **cost**. Hard-drives were *very* expensive “back in the day”, and tape was a much cheaper backup medium. A 40MB hard-drive might have cost $10,000 while a 1GB spool of tape might have cost $250. Like I explained above, tape is *less* reliable because it **does** degrade over time due to its layered nature.

Comment: ` No rewriting of the data does not recharge this magnetic charges on a drive?`   If you copy all of the data from a hard-drive to somewhere, then copy it all back, then yes, it will be “refreshed”. If you expect to store a drive for a decade, then sure, pull it out every five or so years and copy it to another drive, then back again. But the drive might die from mechanical failure (dried bearings, etc.) before magnetic decay becomes a problem. Many people (myself included) still have old hard-drives, floppy disks, etc. from 10, 15, 25+ years that are still readable.

Comment: Thanks for the details, misunderstood some stuff translated the "absent a strong external magnetic field" thing in a wrong way I guess. I translated this to "If a strong magnetic field is missing" still not sure what this means if not this ;) Anyway so my thought that it will get refreshed if true and even if this is it does not matter at all this persons thoughts were not totally stupid. And about tape drives: U teached me that I really got that wrong I thought they were indeed longer lasting and perfect to store somewhere for decades. Cant upvote ;)

Comment: I’ll explain it differently: `you mean that the disk will maybe lose its data after 10 years either way its its running daily or never ran at all?`   Yes, even without a very strong magnetic field (opening the drive and swiping a super-magnet on the disk), it will *still* degrade over time because the Earth’s magnetic field is weak enough that it will take a long time to “drag” the magnetic particles in the platters out of their state. If you leave a drive unused for a *very* long time, it will *eventually* be wiped. Unless you want to store the data *forever*, then it should not be a problem.

Comment: For the record, even if you *do* use a drive, it won’t affect the existing data (much). If you write a file, then reading and writing *other* files won’t “refresh” the first file. *Reading* the first file *might* help a little, but deleting it and writing it back is the only way to truly make sure it has the “full charge”. Again, this is mostly theoretical and is rarely a problem in real life.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true. There is no magnetic force "going on inside" a hard drive that need be recharged or anything. Bits are saved as a super tiny magnetic charge that can be deleted by the magnetic field of the earth and cosmic radiation. That means your data will eventually be lost at some point but that is estimated to take up to 10 years and more.
This is more due to the magnetic field of the earth than cosmic radiation which is more a threat to running Systems (hence the reason why ECC RAM exists).

Using the disk is not making the disk healthier in any way, the only benefit from using the disk regulary is that you can check the disk for failures and resuce your data from corruption but it will not "replenish" you hard drive.

Comment: With "magnetic force in there" I meant exactly what you are talking about. So this magnetic charge might go away after 10 years you say. So if I take that drive for a run after 9 years this magnetic charges not get renewed? Do I actually need to rewrite the data to make that happen? Or you mean that the disk will maybe lose its data after 10 years either way its its running daily or never ran at all?